# Why Installing Roo Support fails on Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers 2020-09 (4.17.0) Build id: 20200910-1200 with STS 4.8.0

Tags: eclipse, spring-roo, spring-tools-4

Tried installing Spring-Roo support from: Spring IDE - http://dist.springframework.org/release/IDE/

Fails with:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Spring IDE Roo Support 3.9.14.202009150957-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.feature.group 3.9.14.202009150957-RELEASE)
Missing requirement: Spring IDE Roo Support 3.9.14.202009150957-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.feature.group 3.9.14.202009150957-RELEASE) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 2.0.1' but it could not be found

Environment:

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Build id: 20200910-1200
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 14.0.2

+Installed Spring Tools 4 (aka Spring Tools Suite 4) 4.8.0 release from Eclipse Marketplace.

I am almost sure that I have seen something about the version of Eclipse that cannot be fresher than xxxx   in order to use STS and Spring-Roo as workaround but cannot find that neither any more... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Spring IDE Roo Support from:
https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.9.14.RELEASE/e4.17

or via the `STS3 Add-On Pack for Spring Tools 4` from the Eclipse Marketplace.

But please keep in mind that the IDE support for Roo is no longer maintained and will soon no longer be available to be installed into Spring Tools 4 or Eclipse.